# How to prompt a app selector for the user to choose an app from?

Tags: react-native

In my application the user can download a pdf file. After the download completes I want to allow the user to choose an app from those installed to open the file.
What I've tried was:

```
export const openWith = async (filePath: string ) => {
    try {
        let path = `content://${filePath}`;
        let supported = await Linking.canOpenURL(path);
        if (supported) {
            await Linking.openURL(path)
        } else {
            throw new Error('Unsupported file.')
        }
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

However I get an error:

```
Could not open URL my_file_url exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

I have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in my manifest.